# NBA Stats JSON Parsing Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

Can someone help me parse this to get data in Swift 4. Im not sure exactly how to parse data like this with SwiftyJSON.

http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguestandingsv3?LeagueID=00&Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular+Season

For Example: Print the "WinPCT" of the Warriors

```
import SwiftyJSON

var nbaData: Data!

    let url = URL(string: "http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguestandingsv3?LeagueID=00&Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular+Season")

    do {
        nbaData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)

            let json = try JSON(data: nbaData)

                //json["WinPCT"]["Warriors"] something like this


    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Trying to accomplish something like this with the data.
Print **win percentage** of the **warriors.**

```
for item in json["resultSets"].arrayValue {

print(item["Warriors/WinPTC"].stringValue)

}
```

**I just want to get all the data in the row set [ ] of a specific team and to pick that data one by one such as standing, wins, losses etc..**

For example:

```
let warriorsRecord = json["Warriors"]["WarriorsRecord"]
let warriorsWins = json["Warriors"]["Wins"]
let warriorsLosses = json["Warriors"]["Losses"]
//etc...
```

*Your welcome stats analysts **;)**

Comment: Still your question is not clear enough. `WinPTC` is in `headers` and `Warriors` is in `rowSet`. What is the relation b/w both?

Comment: OK then the current record of the warriors then.

Comment: I just want to get all the data in the row set [ ] of a specific team and to pick that data one by one such as standing, wins, losses etc...

Comment: @husharoonie give a try to my answer, it works

Comment: @husharoonie See the edited part of my answer. Its a clean and short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requested JSON brings one array with parameters and another array with data, so you need to locate the index of your requested statistic and search in the data array for that index,

**You only have to pass them the required parameters**

**Here you have**

```
func getStadisticsFromTeam(jsonObject:JSON,teamName:String,stadisticsName:String,closure:@escaping (String?)->Void) {
    let resultSetsDict = jsonObject["resultSets"][0]
    var stadisticsIndex = -1
    var nameIndex = -1
    if let arrayOFHeaders = resultSetsDict["headers"].array {
        for (index,value) in arrayOFHeaders.enumerated() {
            if(value.stringValue == stadisticsName) {
                stadisticsIndex = index
            }
            if(value.stringValue == "TeamName") {
                nameIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
    if(stadisticsIndex == -1 || nameIndex == -1) {
        closure(nil)
    }
    
    if let resultRows = resultSetsDict["rowSet"].array {
        let warriorsData = resultRows.filter({$0.array![nameIndex].stringValue == teamName})
        let desiredValue = warriorsData[0].array![stadisticsIndex].stringValue
        closure(desiredValue)
    }
}

func loadStaticsReportData(teamName:String,stadisticsName:String,closure:@escaping (String?)->Void)
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguestandingsv3?LeagueID=00&Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular+Season")
    
    do {
        let nbaData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        
        let json = try JSON(data: nbaData)
        
        self.getStadisticsFromTeam(jsonObject: json, teamName: teamName, stadisticsName: stadisticsName, closure: closure)
        //json["WinPCT"]["Warriors"] something like this
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

you can pass any Team name and any stadistic to this method

**Example with Warriors and WinPCT**

```
    self.loadStaticsReportData(teamName: "Warriors", stadisticsName: "WinPCT") { (value) in
        if(value != nil) {
        debugPrint(value)
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

> "0.746"

**Others inputs and Outputs**

> **Input** teamName: "Warriors", stadisticsName: "TeamCity" **Ouput** "Golden State"
>
> **Input** teamName: "Warriors", stadisticsName: "LongHomeStreak" **Ouput** "8"
>
> **Input** teamName: "Pistons", stadisticsName: "WinPCT" **Ouput** "0.444"

Answer (score 1):

I ran your url request in postman.. you have three keys..

you extract values using swiftyJson like this:

```
var resourceString = json["resource"].stringValue

var resultSets = json["resultSets"].arrayValue
```

[image]

so you can continue like this

```
var resultDictionary = resultSets[0].dictionaryValue
var rowSetArray = resultDictionary["rowSet"].arrayValue
```

Now your rewSetArray contains array of details where each element corresponds to detail corresponding to one team.
you can create a mode class for each team and save data in that model class with headers as class variables..

then run for each loop on rowSetArray

```
var teamInfoDict = [[String: Any]]()

for row in rowSetArray {

    var headersArray = resultDictionary["headers"].arrayValue
    var teamDict = [String: Any]()
    var count = 0
    for header in headersArray {
        teamDict[header.stringValue] = row.arrayValue[count]
        count += 1
    }

    teamInfoDict.append(teamDict)
}
```

By this time, teamInfoDict will have all values corresponding to each key that was in headers

Comment: I understand that but how can i get  //json["WinPCT"]["Warriors"] something like this. The win percentage of the warriors?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguestandingsv3?LeagueID=00&Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular+Season")

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let json = try JSON(data: data)

        let headers = json["resultSets"][0]["headers"]
        let rowSet = json["resultSets"][0]["rowSet"]

        /// rowSet is an array
        var teamInfo: JSON?
        for (index, teamJson):(String, JSON) in rowSet {
            // Do something you want

            /// Get team sho has name "Warriors"
            if teamJson.arrayValue[4].stringValue == "Warriors" {
                teamInfo = teamJson
                break
            }

            if teamInfo != nil {
                break
            }
        }

        // Here is information of Team "Warriors". 
        print(teamInfo?.arrayValue)

        /// And here is the `WinPCT` which is at 14th position in `headers` 
        print(tempInfo?.arrayValue[14].stringValue)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

**EDITED**
Hers is the `Swift` smart way.

```
/// 4 is the Index of `TeamName` in headers. By same way you can filter other things too.
let teamInfo = rowSet.filter({$0.1.arrayValue[4].rawString() == "Warriors"})
print(teamInfo.first?.1.arrayValue)

/// `WinPCT` which is at 14th position in `headers`
print(teamInfo.first?.1.arrayValue[14].stringValue)
```

**Note:** The index of key in headers and the value in this array are same. Example:- `TeamName` at 4th position in headers array and `"Warriors"` is at 4th position in `teamInfo` so you can get whatever you want by index.